# Is it possible to convert a SoapException to a FaultException with WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing

I am migrating a web service client from [WSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements) to [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation).

I already modified the internal fault and error handling to deal with FaultExceptions instead of SoapExceptions.

The project has an extensive suite of test cases to test the fault and error handling which still relies on SoapException. For various reasons, I'd prefer not to rewrite them all.

Is it possible to just convert the SoapException into a FaultException and thereby running the old test cases against the new error handling code?

Comment: I had this exact same problem, and I was sort of appalled when I saw how poor the responses to this question were. I'm giving it a bounty in hopes that someone notices it, even though it's pretty old.

Comment: Cool, but I guess this just isn't possible. I have moved on and am no longer working on this project. IIRC, I just ended up swallowing the bitter pill and changing it everywhere. But I don't remember any details.

Comment: For 1 thing, I think the wording has it reversed, don't you want FaultExceptiom -> SoapException (for testing) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, no, no, no! That's the whole point. I *have* a SoapException and I want to *get* an equivalent FaultException.

Comment: @JSBangs: I read that in your comments (later). But it still makes little sense, I read: you have converted to WCF (FaultExceptions) and have a test suite that wants SoapExceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a message inspector ? Have you checked the [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) ?

It may look like this :

The message inspector

```
public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
     ...

    #region IClientMessageInspector Members
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
      //rethrow your exception here, parsing the Soap message
        if (reply.IsFault)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

            object faultDetail = //read soap detail here;

            ...
        }
    }
    #endregion

     ...
}
```

The endpoint behavior

```
public class MessageInspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
     ...

    #region IEndpointBehavior Members
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        MessageInspector inspector = new MessageInspector();
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);  
    }
    #endregion

     ...
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx

I think a good practice is to [use exceptions as faults too](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/).

Comment: JSBangs, I'll rely on you to tell me whether this works for you, in which case I'll mark it as an accepted answer. (Only I can hand out your bounty now, correct?)

Comment: Considering that JSBangs gave you his bounty, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. I don't immediately see how this is related and don't have the means to investigate, however.

Answer (score 2):

how about

catching `SoapException` and throwing  `FaultException` (a solution, not recommendation)

```
catch(SoapException)
{
 throw new FaultException(); // something similar
}
```

Comment: I probably shouldn't have said "wrap the SoapException into a FaultException" (edited out now) as that was quite misleading. Of course I want the FaultException to preserve all the properties of the SoapException (i.e. code, message, detail, etc.), so that the unit tests can run the existing asserts on the error handling code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [EnterpriseLibrary](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) to convert the FaultException to a SoapException at a particular boundary, in this case client proxy.

Comment: Again, I want to convert *from* a SoapException *to* a FaultException, not the other way around! But I'll look into the EnterpriseLibrary, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to implement [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx). In HandleError method, rethrow exception wrapped to SoapException. Latter you have to register it globally(web.config or whatever).

Example of how this will help (pseudo code):

```
public SoapErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
   public void HandleError(Exception ex)
   {
      throw new SoapException(ex.Message, ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that would help me to convert *from* a SoapException *to* a FaultException.

Comment: Sorry, still the wrong direction. :) I guess this would help if I wanted to convert a FaultException into a SoapException. However, I do not, as stated above.